# Changes to my.ini Not Persisting when using MySQL

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I'm attempting to update some variables for my `MySQL` database server; I am running `Maria` version `10.3.12` on a `Windows 10 64-bit` laptop. I have attempted to update the `my.ini` file located here:

```
C:\Program Files\MariaDB 10.3\data\my.ini
```

I am adding the following lines to a rather simple my.ini

```
max_allowed_packet=64M
interactive_timeout=86400
wait_timeout=86400
```

I have saved the changes to the my.ini; but when I restart the database server using `mysqld restart` at the command console, and then log back into the client, I expect to see my changes using `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'max%'` and what I end up seeing is the default value. The default value for `max_allowed_packet` is about 16M and for the other two it is 28800.

There are numerous articles that relate to this; having poured over them I am aware of how to use the `SET` command to update these from within the client. My goal though is to make a permanent change.

I have no doubt I have overlooked something; any feedback is appreciated.

Comment: What section of the config file are these settings in ?

Answer (score 1):

You can identify path of the configuration file by looking into services:

- Open services and find MariaDB Service instance
- Right click and click on Properties
- You should see something like `"C:\path\to\exe" --defaults-file="c:\path-to-ini\my.ini"`

then you can edit correct configuration file

Comment: I checked this but unfortunately it only confirms I'm using the correct one: `"C:\Program Files\MariaDB 10.3\bin\mysqld.exe" "--defaults-file=C:\Program Files\MariaDB 10.3\data\my.ini" "MySQL"`

Comment: see the my.ini locations for windoes **Option File Locations on Windows** at https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/configuring-mariadb-with-option-files/

Comment: Thank you for posting this; I had in my prior research found this page and gone over those locations. I have gone over them a second time to double check and none of the ancillary locations reflected an additional `my.ini` nor did a general Windows Search reveal anything I wasn't already aware of.

Comment: then you can check global locations which mariadb looks from the link provided by @BerndBuffen

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. After making the changes noted in my post I was attempting to restart MySQL daemon using the Windows Command line and the following command:

```
C:\Users\david>mysqld restart
2019-03-14 21:05:48 0 [Note] mysqld (mysqld 10.3.12-MariaDB) starting as process 8548 ...
```

The results can be seen below the command which is `mysqld restart`

MySQL being installed and run as a Service, clearly this was not the was to restart it; so I restarted it using the `Services.msc`:

1. Typing `Services.msc` into the search bar
2. Selecting `Services`
3. In the `Services` app find `MySQL`
4. Right clicking `MySQL` and selecting
   Restart

This caused the `my.ini` file to be reread.